# Change android edittext Cursor color dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to change the android edittext cursor color with respect to background color of the android edittext(dynamically)?.If I choose dark background color for edittext, cursor would be light.If  I choose dark background color for edittext, cursor would be dark.Based on edittext color change the cursor color will change at runtime.How to achieve this? any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this attribute it will work android:textCursorDrawable

```
<  EditText   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"  
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Field f = null;
 f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
 f.setAccessible(true);
 f.set(editText, R.drawable.color);
```

Comment: What if we want to change pointer color? You can answer me here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240065/edittext-cursor-and-pointer-color-for-below-android-5-0